# Turn US Map into State Links

Tags: html, css

I may have done something dumb - I quickly promised a client I could turn their US Map image into individual state links - but now that I'm thinking about it, even if I do each state as an image, the images will be square, meaning there will be empty space at the edge of each image that will overlap other states, making it so the links overlap. Is there a better way to do this, or any way at all?

Comment: Do you **must** use their US map, or you can use some other US map?

Comment: They have one as part of their site design that is sized and colored to fit the scheme of the site. Is there another option if I can use a different map?

Comment: Try [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/interactive-maps-generator/full_screen_preview/3272382). Here are [examples](http://codecanyon.net/item/interactive-maps-generator/full_screen_preview/3272382)

Answer (score 1):

The links in client-side imagemaps don't have to be rectangles; they can be arbitrary polygons.  So you can make each state clickable without overlapping, and get as close as you want to its "real" borders (depending how high-res your overall map image is).

Defining these polygons pixel-by-pixel is obviously tedious, so most people use programs that build the HTML code for you.  Google "imagemap editor" for one that works on your OS (you don't say if you're using a Mac or PC).  [Here's one](http://www.boutell.com/mapedit/) that says it comes with a USA map already defined!

Comment: I'm using a Mac. I definitely anticipated it being tedious, so that's not a big deal. But I will check this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look at this  [example at w3schools:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)
which uses html 5

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

you can create polygons like this:

```
<area SHAPE='poly' HREF="new.html" ALT="New!" TITLE="New!"
COORDS="150,217, 190,257,  150,297,  110,257">
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks! Is that any different from an image map like Dreamweaver creates?